# How to combine PHP echo and get together?

Tags: php, echo

My website has multiple languages, and I have a PHP line in below that it get data from sql and it shows text on page:

```
<?php get_footer_menu_items(3, "col-md-6 go-right","ftitle go-text-right","footerlist go-right go-text-right" );?>
```

The number 3 in above code is for **text (About Us)**

But in my page, I have another PHP echo that it show text based on selected language:

```
<?php echo trans('0295');?>
```

This above line is for text (About Us)

how can I combine these two lines together that it will change text to selected language?

Comment: Can you post more information about the function? It's hard to decipher. We would have to see the functions in order to give you proper feedback or suggestions for adjustments to your function.

Comment: you should be search for get_footer_menu_items and then change it.

Comment: I searched a lot that's why I posted a question here

Comment: We can't guess what the code of the function `get_footer_menu_items` is, and what it is supposed to do. You must tell us this information.

Answer (score 0):

get_footer_menu_items function **probably** takes integer as first argument and then as index in an array of some sort with text strings.

So if you call it like this:

```
get_footer_menu_items(trans('0295'), "col-md-6 go-right","ftitle go-text-right","footerlist go-right go-text-right" );
```

it won't work anyway.
Without mentioned function's code it's hard to help.

Comment: Just like I said. If you don't include code of get_footer_menu_items function here, nobody will be able to help you.